# Why I can't change language in wordpress dashboard?

Tags: php, wordpress

Good evening, I have a problem with changing the language in my WP dashboard. 
In my wp-content/languages
[image]

When I change language from English to another in WP settings nothing is changed in dashboard and language is stay English. But new language is applied for top 
[image]

Thank's for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change language in user profile settings.

[image]